# How the display the string with tags like "<para>", <emphasis> in UIwebview in correct format?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I just a parsed a response from webservice, from the response I've to show the received data for a particular key in UIWebview. The data that have to show in Uiwebview contains some special tags like ,  and etc., Please advise how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Note1:

We don't have emphasis tag in html tags:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/
```

so browser Can not understand the code. but you can handle it in 2 way.

1. Add some css to the current tag.

   emphasis{ font-style: italic; }
2. Replace it with  tag which is known by browser

You can add some CSS codes to the UIWebView and format them as you like.
The HTML Tag are the tags that you have received from web service. the baseURL is working for Images or relative links. for example if you have

```
<a href='pica.jpg'>mypic</a>
```

and baseurl is

```
http://example.com
```

the final url will be

```
http://example.com/pica.jpg
```

and if it is in your Document of application you can use:

```
func getBaseUrl() -> NSURL{
    var pref = prefrences()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String // Document folder of application
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir, isDirectory: true)
    return url!
}
```

this function return a directory from root.

```
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://thebasepath.com/files")
var htmlContentTemplate =
    "<!DOCTYPE html >" +
        "<html dir=\"ltr\" " +
        "  <head>" +
        "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">" +
        "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />" +
        "    <style>" +
        "    emphasis{ font-style: italic; }" +
        "    </style>" +
        "  </head>" +
        "  <body dir=\"rtl\" >" +
        "    <div>%1$s</div>" +
        "<script>\n" +
        "window.onload= function()\n" +
        "{\n" +
    "// your javscript code can be here"
    "}" +
        "</script>" +
        "  </body>" +
    "</html>";
    var final = htmlContentTemplate.replace("%1$s", withString: "your html in body tag")
    var data  = final.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false);
    webView.loadData(data, MIMEType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF8", baseURL: baseURL)
```

to add Replace function to String Data type add below code. the below code can be added to any swift file.

```
extension String
{
func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
{
    return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: what I've provide for baseurl and in the "some html tags"?? just tell me a example

Comment: @GobinathEd Added a sample of Base URL it should be NSURL Type

Comment: Please tell help what I've to provide in the place of "your html in body tag" and for base URL

Comment: you said you have fetched a html tag from web service . your html in body tag are the data that you have recieved from webserivce. and base URL can help if you have some images stored in local device or from a specified domain.

Comment: Ok where I've add the replace function

Comment: the replace function can be in any swift file in project. it can find it. but my recommendation is cerate a swift file and paste the string codes into it.

Comment: if the answer is working. please choose it as answer.

Comment: the string that received from response have <emphasis emphasis-type="italic"> tag its not reflecting in the webview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95918/discussion-between-gobinath-ed-and-ehsan-razm-khah).

Comment: We don't have emphasis tag in html tags  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ so browser can not understand it. but you can add some css to it. or replace it with a regular expression to <em> which is a known html tag by browser

Comment: Please tell me how to do that

Comment: Check answer. i added in both on top with details and in codes. @GobinathEd

Comment: your answer is correct. But please help me how to define the tags <emphasis emphasis-type="italic"><emphasis emphasis-type="bold"> in css

Comment: you have to do it with Regular Expressions. and emphasis must work. I checked it in playground